# Is it possible to implement paging without segmentation? x86

Tags: x86, x86-64, paging, osdev, windows-kernel

I've been told that segmentation is required for paging, why is that? AFAIK most systems with UEFI will start in long mode which I assume would not require segmentation at all?

Comment: Having some descriptors (like CS) referring to valid GDT entries is necessary for the machine to work at all in long / protected mode even on x86-64.  You're not really using segmentation, though, so it depends on your definition of "without segmentation".  If you mean "with a flat memory model", yes, the ISA doesn't support anything else in 64-bit mode, except for FS and GS bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it's impossible to disable segmentation on 80x86; even in long mode (where `fs` and `gs` still work, sort of).

Instead you "fake disable" segmentation by setting the base of segment registers to zero and the limit to max.; so that segmentation does nothing. Modern CPUs are specially optimized for this case (they don't do the addition in the "linear address = segment_base + offset" calculation if they know segment bases are zero anyway).

Because of this it's possible to say that segmentation is required (with or without paging); and that segmentation isn't required (can be "fake disabled") for paging.

Note that most operating systems "fake disable" segmentation and only use paging; except for `fs` and `fs` which are often (ab)used as a pointer to thread local or "CPU local" data (and aren't actually used for the properties of segments).